# Excel-VBA:How to Get the last column which contains data in a excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vb script which copy `n` number of columns from one workbook to another as of now I am using below code to copy which is copying upto only certain columns (In this case `H`).

```
Columns("A:H").Copy
```

How do I copy the till the last data filled column?

Comment: have you tried recording a macro of the action of using CTRL-RIGHT ARROW on the worksheet? This will give you some code to work with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the UsedRange property of the Worksheet objet if you want to be sure not to miss out on any data

```
Worksheets("YOUR_WS").UsedRange.copy
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the column numbers for this task;

```
LastColNr = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Columns(1), Columns(LastColNr)).Copy
```